# GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[...]] syntax problem

Tags: plotting, geography

I am simply trying to plot the above position, but always got error message:

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[{40.6643,-73.9385}]]
```

> LatitudeLongitude::invloc: GeoPosition[-73.9385] is not a valid location specification.

The above numbers are taken from a mathematica example:

```
 GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]]
```

> ```
> GeoPosition[{40.6643,-73.9385}]
> ```

thanks!

Comment: Try enclosing the `GeoPosition[]` object in a list: `GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]]}]`.

Comment: that doesn't solve my problem.  I just use that number for example, and just to show that I did use good numbers here.  My original purpose is to plot a geoPosition for which I only have latitude and longttitude numbers.

Comment: `GeoPosition[{40.6643, -73.9385}] // Point // GeoGraphics` works well. But `GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[{40.6643, -73.9385}]]` in V11.1 is ok too.

Comment: `GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[{40.6643, -73.9385}]]` also works in 10.4; what version and OS are you on?

Comment: I am working on 11.0.  That might be the reason.  let me update my software.  Thanks.